# Previewing users text with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to achieve the functionality that this editor has got with its preview feature.

I have got this html:

```
    <textarea id="tbMsg" style="height:450px;width:100%;"></textarea>
```

I want whatever is in the textarea above to go onto this div, every 2 secs or so.

```
      <DIV id="preview" style="BORDER-RIGHT: #c0c0c0 1px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 3px; 
    BORDER-TOP: #c0c0c0 1px solid; PADDING-LEFT: 3px; PADDING-BOTTOM: 3px; BORDER-LEFT: #c0c0c0 1px solid; WIDTH: 660px; 
    PADDING-TOP: 3px; BORDER-BOTTOM: #c0c0c0 1px solid; HEIGHT: 700px"></DIV>
```

I have this javascript/jquery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
    $('#tbMsg').keyup( function() {
        alert(1);
        var text = $(this).val();
        $('#preview').html(text);
    });
});​
    </script>
```

Alert 1 never happens, which means that the request wasnt successful. Where does my jquery goes wrong?

Comment: Welcome back ,is you editor problem solved? I have posted a whole new answer meeting your needs :)

Comment: yeah, I used bbcode editor..very simple, and safer than cute php and ckeditor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might want to consider doing a [keyUp detection](http://jsfiddle.net/VEFn6/) instead of timed sync.

```
$(function() {
    $('#tbMsg').on('keyup', function() {
        var text = $(this).val();
        $('#preview').html(text);
    });
});​
```

Comment: The problem it doesnt have to be on keyup , does it.. what if the guy copies and pastes,,will it still work?

Comment: why your code doesnt work?!?!..jquery is loaded..and when i put alert inisde it, it gives me the alert...

Comment: [works here](http://jsfiddle.net/VEFn6/1/). check the console for errors. also, load jQuery before your scripts.

Comment: My jquery isnt even loading...also.I have both divs in table cells.does it matter?

Comment: 'input' event also suits here.

Answer (score 0):

When the page loads, the conditional:

```
if (bbcode != $("#tbMsg").val())
```

fails, because bbcode is "" and the textarea is empty.

Comment: yeah,,but when I type something, it should call the get

Comment: Ah yes.  Is the server returning a 200 Status OK?